# Fabric UI Modal custom sizing

Tags: reactjs, spfx, fluent-ui

Please help to customize [Fabric UI Modal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/modal) window. I've tried to minimize height and remove vertical scrolling. Tried to work with `containerClassName`, `className`, `scrollableContentClassName` - but none of them work.

In scss file:

```css
.modal {
    overflow-y: "unset";
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 80vh
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this class `ms-Modal-scrollableContent`.
[image]

Comment: Can you show js-file? I can't see witch props you are using

Comment: Can you please show <Modal > component without content

Comment: I mean show me how you call thes component
Like this:
<Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={hideModal}
        isBlocking={false}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
        dragOptions={isDraggable ? dragOptions : undefined}
      >

Comment: Would like to know how to implement this as well if possible! I'm using SPFX and need to remove horizontal scroll bar.